# After being employed for 6 months, I forgot to update my CV to not be actively looking

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

So, I used my Careers CV to help bring in work when I was looking last year. I finally went to update it today and realized that it still had me listed as actively looking for work, despite me having had a good job for more than 6 months I'm fairly content with.

This may seem a bit obvious. Why didn't I just update my CV? Well, I got busy and forgot about it. I'm sure that I'm not the only one who has done this.

I think that this can cause problems for the businesses searching for candidates. They don't want to waste their time sending me a (hopefully individualized) message, when I'm not even looking for a new job. I assume on the business side, there are ways to target either passive or active candidates. I expect that I'm not the only one to have forgotten about this, and this makes the filtering on passive/active less useful

I propose a feature request for one of these two behaviors:

1. Email me after 3 or 6 months, notifying me that I am still listed as looking for work, despite me not doing any job searches
2. Email me after 3 or 6 months, asking if I still am actually looking for work. If I don't somehow notify that I saw this email, then automatically switch me to being "passive" rather than "active".

I lean towards #1, as it's less invasive, but I'd be glad to hear opinions on either one and why either one is bad / the whole spirit of this feature request is bad

Answer (score 11):

Meh. I'd rather have Careers not pester me frequently. There's enough sites that do that and I hate them all and have turned all E-Mail notifications off where possible.

As a user, I'd say the current behaviour is fine. If an employer contacts me even though I'm no longer looking for work, that will be enough of a wake-up call for me to flip the switch. As long as the only thing the employer loses is a couple minutes of effort, I don't think there is a problem.

Maybe a "I'm no longer looking for work" link could be embedded in the notification E-Mail (If it isn't already there?).

Answer (score 1):

We track the last edit date of all profiles and send an email reminding you to update your profile every 3 months when passing that threshold.

Comment: But that's just a general reminder... When I received it I though "well, I'm just started at my job, so no real need to update my CV right now"